# Unable to add $PATH in zshrc

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to add the Hashicorp `vault` exec to my `$PATH` variable in `~/.zshrc`.

Below steps were followed:

1. Edit the `.zshrc` `$PATH` as below:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/myuserName/Downloads/flyway-6.0.4:/Users/myUserName/Documents/vault:$PATH
   ```
2. Saved the `.zshrc` file
3. Sourced the `.zshrc` file with the command `source ~/.zshrc` and even restarted terminal

Upon typing the `vault` command, I get `command not found` error.
Help needed.

Comment: since the exec file is pointed here, do i need to add an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: I was pointing to the executable file in the path directly rather than pointing to just the folder.

Upon changing the Path from

```
/Users/myUserName/Documents/vault
```

to

```
/Users/myUserName/Documents/
```

the issue is fixed.

Comment: Note that it's not very usual to put an executable in `~/Documents`. Create a directory `/Users/myUserName/bin` and place it there.

Comment: Yes understood.It was just for a trial.